# Javascript "shift" versus "splice" - are these statements equal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I just want to confirm if the following two Javascript statements produces the same results, as it seems to me:

First:

```
var element = my_array.splice(0,1)[0];
```

Second:

```
var element = my_array.shift();
```

I want to substitute the first by the second, in my own code, to improve readability. Can I do this?

Comment: http://www.webartzforum.com/t3019-javascript-shift-slice-splice

Answer (score 57, accepted):

They will have the same effect, yes. `splice(0, 1)` will remove the first element from `my_array` and return a new array containing that element. `shift` will do the same, but return the element itself, not an array.

`shift` is more readable (in my opinion) and is also [significantly faster](http://jsperf.com/shift-vs-splice) (in Chrome at least):

[image]

Comment: I've upvoted everybody's answer - but chosen yours because of the extra performance graphic and information. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 6):

Both lines of code remove the first element from the array, and return the removed element, they are both supported in all major browsers.

You should use the second one, and the code will be more readable indeed.

Answer (score 2):

[shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) returns the element that was removed, [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array of elements that were removed.

that being said, the two statements do the same thing and i would agree that the second is more readable.

Answer (score -1):

**splice** will return as an array but not remove data from the object instead make a copy

---

**shift** just give one data from front and also remove from object

---

For example,

```
const object = {1}
object.slice(); // return [{1}]
//object will be : {1}
object.shift(); // return {1}
//object will be : {} as shift remove the front data
```

Comment: First, the code example itself is wrong. Second I think you mixed up splice and slice. Splice does indeed mutates the array i.e. it _will_ modify the original array as does shift. Slice on the other hand doesn't mutate the array and returns a new one.